# How do I open visio diagrams without a copy of visio loaded locally?

Tags: microsoft-visio, image-viewer

I have two systems I use on a regular basis. I use one for presentations and the other I use to do my work. I have Visio on my main system but I do not have it on my other system I am using for the presentation.  Is there a way to open these diagrams so that I can display the content without having the full up version of Visio installed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try the Microsoft [Visio 2007 document viewer](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=d88e4542-b174-4198-ae31-6884e9edd524&displaylang=en)

Answer (score 2):

You can use Microsoft's Visio viewer. You can also use [Lucidchart's Visio Viewer](https://www.lucidchart.com/pages/tour/visio_viewer) functionality which is an online application that imports/exports Visio files.  If you wish to make changes, there is a fee involve.  It is free to view

That would allow you to also make changes, if necessary, to your diagram when you don't have access to Visio.

Answer (score 1):

You could upload your document to `Lucidhart.com` for free using their Visio Import feature. It only costs money if you edit the diagram.

Comment: How is this different form the answer by @J M in October 2012?

Comment: It is important to note when you will hit Lucidchart's paywall. Open/view is free, whereas editing costs money.

Comment: Noted- I have edited the earlier answer to include the info.  The main page linked in the October 2103 reply does make it clear that there are fees as it reports it is "affordable" and Pricing is in the top banner